# R ggplot2 fix legend text to a value and color

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors

I have a list `l` of numbers (in my case 3600, representing different categories (0,2,3,4,5,6,7,8) which I'd calculated before). Now I want to plot a grid, where each number in the list represents a specific color (i.e 0 -> always black, 3 -> always orange...).

But instead of the numbers, I want the explanation of the categories in the legend. And my code works fine when all the categories are in my list. In some cases not every category appears in my list(depends on data).

How can I link the label with the category(number) so that in any cases the right color will be represented or rather the right description for the color?

```
# example list
l <- list(sample(c(0,2:8), 3600, replace = TRUE))

# building a data.frame for the grid
C <- as.data.frame(unlist(l))
colnames(C) <- c("category")

y.df <- rep(1:60, each = 60)
x.df <- rep(1:60, times = 60)
z.df <- rep(1:3600, times = 1)

C <- cbind(C, x = x.df, y = y.df, node_chem = z.df)

myColors <- c("black", "darkorchid1", "orange", "red",
              "springgreen", "darkgreen", "cyan", "white")
names(myColors) <- c ("0", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8")

ggplot(data=C, aes(x = x, y = y,  color = factor(C$category))) +    
  geom_point() +

  # background = white
  theme_bw() +

  scale_color_manual(name= "category",
                     values= myColors,
                     labels = c("category 0", "category 2", "category 3", "category 4", 
                                "icategory 5", "category 6", "category 7", "category 8")) +

  #scale_colour_gradientn(colours=rainbow(4)) +
  ggtitle("my map")
```

Here the output when all categories have been calculated before:

[image]

Comment: You already know to use a named vector for values in `scale_color_manual`. Why not use another named vector for labels? Also, consider replacing `color = factor(C$category)` with `color = factor(category)`. There's no need to use the dollar sign within `aes()`.

Comment: I don't understand the issues. Could you (a) use `set.seed` before your `sample` so your simulated data is exactly reproducible? (b) Use a smaller example that may be easier to follow? 3600 points may be your real data size, but it might be easier to understand if you show us, say, 36 points. (c) Explain a little more what your need is? What is wrong with the plot you show?

Comment: @Z.Lin : Thank U...I solved it with a second named vector...

Answer (score 0):

Make a column which contains the category labels, then you can supply that to the color aesthetic.

```
# example list
l <- list(sample(c(0,2:8), 3600, replace = TRUE))

# building a data.frame for the grid
C <- as.data.frame(unlist(l))
colnames(C) <- c("category")

y.df <- rep(1:60, each = 60)
x.df <- rep(1:60, times = 60)
z.df <- rep(1:3600, times = 1)

C <- cbind(C, x = x.df, y = y.df, node_chem = z.df)

myColors <- c("black", "darkorchid1", "orange", "red",
              "springgreen", "darkgreen", "cyan", "white")

# change the named vector to match the category labels
names(myColors) <- paste("category", c("0", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"), sep = " ")

# make a new column containing the desired category labels
C$category2 <-  paste("category", C$category, sep = " ")

ggplot(data = C, aes(x = x, y = y,  color = factor(category2))) +    
  geom_point() +

  # background = white
  theme_bw() +

  scale_color_manual(name= "category",
                     values= myColors) +

  ggtitle("my map")
```

Now if you take out one of the categories it will still work, because your named vector in `scale_color_manual` will map the color correctly:

```
ggplot(data = C[C$category != 0,], aes(x = x, y = y,  color = factor(category2))) +    
geom_point() +

  # background = white
  theme_bw() +

  scale_color_manual(name= "category",
                     values= myColors) +

  ggtitle("my map")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks...but this would only work when I wanted labels like "category 0" and so on...but I have names like "butter", "fish" and so on...I really dont know how to set the labels when there are not every category represented in my data

Comment: The way I constructed the category labels just relates to your example.